# GWT, generating an asynchronous interface from a synchronous interface in Eclipse à la GWT RemoteService - how to?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, asynchronous, auto-generate

I am using GWT's generator features to abstract a javascript library, auto generating code based on methods contained in some marker interface so they can be treated like GWT's `RemoteService`s even though behind-the-scenes, something else entirely is going on.  How can I get Eclipse to generate (and possibly update/flag errors in) the associated asynchronous interface?  Please note that I'm not asking how to create an asynchronous version of a `RemoteService`; I know how to do that.  In fact, there is no server communication going on here.  I *am* looking to do something similar so future developers who are familiar with GWT's `RemoteService`s will understand how to use my abstraction.  I have the "behind-the-scenes" stuff working, so I won't bother with the details of that javascript library here.  The question is how to create and maintain an "asychronous" interface according to some arbitrary rules to accompany a developer supplied "synchronous" interface.

For example, some unknown future dev may provide an interface

```
public interface MyFoo extends MyMarkerI {
    void doFoo(String someVar);
    String doBar(String someOtherVar);
}
```

I would like to have eclipse generate the "asynchronous" interface

```
public interface MyFooAsync {
    void doFoo(String someVar); //returns void; callback not needed.
    void doBar(String someOtherVar, SomeCallback<String> callback);
}
```

possibly flagging the following as an error (**in eclipse**, I see the error at compile time) so the developer can re-generate it

```
public interface MyFooAsync { //eclipse red-squigly underline, missing a method
    void doFoo(String someVar);
}
```

Currently, I'm creating and updating the async version manually.  I may not remember to change both interfaces until I go to compile and I get an error.  If possible, I don't want to have to manually maintain both interfaces, especially since there may be many different interfaces marked for processing.  I am not looking for GWT's Generator; that is what I'm using to provide the implementation of `MyFooAsync` at compile time.  I need the Async *interface* created at development (i.e., before compile) time so I can use the type.  E.g.,

```
MyFooAsync foo = (MyFooAsync) GWT.create(MyFoo.class);
```

would not be possible if created using generators since MyFooAsync would not be available.

I imagine this is possible by writing a plugin for eclipse or the compiler, but I've never done that and wouldn't know where to begin.  I can't even find the code GWT is using to generate and maintain their asynchronous interfaces.

I will be happy to provide more clarification if the question is not clear.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd have to write an eclipse plug-in to do this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

Comment: @fred02138 whew, that's definitely non-trivial, but that's what I figured would be necessary; I'm sure the GWT plugin is doing that somewhere.  Thanks for the link!